# Blink highlight a button according to its value changes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have WPF control, it has a list view with many buttons
I need those buttons to blink and highlight for a short time when their binded value changes (to Green when value goes up and to red when it goes down).

What is the best way doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example uses a Trigger to animate the `Foreground` of a Button when its `IsMouseOver` property becomes `Green`.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      WindowTitle="Animate Properties with Storyboards">

  <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PropertyTriggerExampleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" To="Green"  />
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </Trigger.EnterActions>
          <Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>               
      </Style.Triggers>    
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>

  <StackPanel Margin="20">  
    <Button Style="{StaticResource PropertyTriggerExampleButtonStyle}"  />
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Modify `<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">` to your wanted trigger, and do the animation you want.

Comment: Nice. The property Im using wont change it self back like mouse over does, and I need it to be trigered only when there is a change, that  means that when the control loads and the property is already that value I dont want the trigger to fire

Comment: Implement 'inotifypropertychanged' and then modify '<Trigger Property={Binding someprop} Value="somevalue" />'.

Comment: But in that case, if I will load the control and the "someprop" will be set to "somevalue" the trigger will be fired, I dont want it to happen, I want it to happen only if while the control is displayed the value changes